# SVG Sprite is not shown on the page

Tags: html, svg, sass

SVG sprite is not shown if I open the page with browser. Although if i would open the same project to be observed through gulp, the icons would be on the page. what could be the problem?

i tried to change paths, to recompile the sprite with svg store plugin

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you use to load the SVG sprite.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.